# Importing a interface doesn't work, but locally it works

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, ionic2

I'm learning Angular 2 with Ionic and i'm having a problem when importing interfaces from another file.
Here's the code:

```
//event.ts

export interface Event {

eventName: string;
  description: string;
  time: Date;
  location: string;
}
```

Then in my page it goes like this:

```
//pages/events/events.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Event } from '../models/event';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-events',
  templateUrl: 'events.html'
})
export class EventsPage {
  events: Event;
  test: evento;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.events = {},
    this.test = {}
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EventsPage');
  }

}
interface evento {
  nome: string;
  description: string;
  time: Date;
  location: string;
}
```

This code generates 2 errors for me, the first one is: 
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'evento'.
  Property 'nome' is missing in type '{}'

and the second one is: 
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
  Property 'bubbles' is missing in type '{}'

The second one i understand, i only need to fill the fields that i set and then the error is gone. The first one however doesn't make any sense. even when i fill the object with the right fields, it still doesn't recognize the fields i set in the first file.
Can someone shed a light for me about this?

Oh, and when I try to fill the object it gives me this message: 
Type '{ eventName: string; description: string; time: Date; location: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'eventName' does not exist in type 'Event'.

Comment: The first one is strictly identical to the second one.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, fixed the message, i had to copy from the popup...

Comment: Because `{}` does not have the properties declared in the interface. Consider marking them as optional if they are not initially present. Ex: `interface I { p?: T }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I tried to do this as you said, and still got the same error when i fill the object:

Type '{ eventName: string; description: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'eventName' does not exist in type 'Event'

Comment: Looks like the declared `Event` is merging with the global `Event`, but only when it is imported, this is indeed strange. Call it something else.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh my god... After repeating and creating a lot of random files and names... I discovered that I was importing from the wrong file... I was supposed to import from '../../models/event' and since Event is a global name it was importing from somewhere... Really thanks and sorry for the wasted time ¬¬

Comment: Sure, glad you got it worked out.

Comment: @AluanHaddad would you mind adding your comments as an answer to the post, since you help a lot to fix the issue?